# Get Specific Text in a Range of Excel cells using C#

Tags: c#, wpf, excel

I am working in WPF application with excel . In that application i am having a column name as Bulk. That column contains two options like YES and NO as a text. Now i need to indicate the font as red color for YES option and Normal Black color for NO option.
        I got the range of that particular column. But i dont know How shall i get the YES options and NO options seperately and also i need to color that options as per the need.

Here I mentioned my code :

```
foreach(Range Value in range.cells)
{

???????
???????
}
```

Any one pls tell me the solution of this. How shall i proceed this process. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Possibly you asked this question many times http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2453152/cell-color-change-in-excel-using-conditional-formatting-in-c-sharp, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2452417/cell-color-changing-in-excel-using-c-sharp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this [class](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/Excel_and_C_.aspx) to your project and change the namespace to yours and start using it to create what you want in coloring settings

as far as your YES/NO detection, you can do the following:

```
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range range = myworksheet.UsedRange;
        //Start iterating from 1 not zero, 1 is the first row after notation of the current coloumn
        for (int i = 1; i <= range.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range myrange = myworksheet.get_Range(/*your column letter, ex: "A" or "B"*/ + i.ToString(), System.Reflection.Missing.Value);
            string temp = myrange.Text;
            if(temp.Contains("YES"))
            {
                //Do your YES logic
            }
            else if(temp.Contains("NO"))
            {
                //Do your No Logic
            }
        }
```

Comment: Shouldn't that iteration run while `i <= range.Rows.Count` ?

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
string strFileName = "D:\\test1.xlsx";
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application ExcelObj = null;
ExcelObj = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook theWorkbook = ExcelObj.Workbooks.Open(strFileName, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Sheets sheets = theWorkbook.Worksheets;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet worksheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)sheets.get_Item(1);
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range range = worksheet.get_Range("A11", "G21"); // Your requied range here

foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range cell in range.Cells)
{
   if(cell.TextToString()=="Yes")
    {
    }
   if(cell.TextToString()=="No")
    {
    }

}
```

For more information check here

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4zs9xy29(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 0):

As for the Value check on the Cells, you can use the Class that Sherif Mahar Eaid Suggested,
When I use VBA to look for excel cells, I use something that looks more like this

' this is VB script though.

`if (Range("A1").Value = "DesiredString") Then
 Code
End If`

I am almost certain that for cell objects there is a value get method on C#,
and for the colors, I think that

`YourRange.Font.Color = System.Drawing.Color.Black.ToArgb();`

will work...